# What is the probability of drawing 5 cards of the same type from a deck of 52 cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

My textbook has the following problem:

> There is 52 cards in a deck and 13 cards of each type/color. You are drawing 5 cards. Whats the probability of all these 5 cards being the same type?

My solution:

There is a $\frac{52}{52}$ probability of drawing the first card, then a $\frac{12}{51}$ chance of drawing a second card of the same type as the first one and so on...
$$\frac{52}{52} \cdot \frac{12}{51} \cdot \frac{11}{50} \cdot \frac{10}{49} \cdot \frac{9}{48} = \frac{33}{16660}$$

I solved the same problem by calculating the individual probabilities for each card type and then adding all the probabilities together:

$$4\cdot(\frac{13}{52} \cdot \frac{12}{51} \cdot \frac{11}{50} \cdot \frac{10}{49} \cdot \frac{9}{48}) = \frac{33}{16660}$$

My textbook says the solution is $(\frac{13}{51} \cdot \frac{12}{50} \cdot \frac{11}{49} \cdot \frac{10}{48})$ without any explanation. Although I don't see how you arrive at this answer.

Whats wrong with my way of solving the problem and how do you arrive at the textbooks solution?

Comment: Your answer is right, the textbook is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the official solution, there's nothing wrong with your method.  Just for an alternate phrasing: there are $\binom {52}5$ ways to draw a $5$ card hand, and there are $4\times \binom {13}5$ ways to choose a $5$ card flush.  The ratio gives your value.

Comment: The textbook is wrong, your methods are correct.

Comment: $\frac{13}{51} \cdot \frac{12}{50} \cdot \frac{11}{49} \cdot \frac{10}{48}$ is $\frac{12}{51} \cdot \frac{11}{50} \cdot \frac{10}{49} \cdot \frac{9}{48}$ when a person solving forgets that we already have $1$ card of the type when we choose the second one.

Comment: As an aside, rather than "type/color" the traditional name here is "[Suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card_suit)" to represent which of $\clubsuit,\diamondsuit,\heartsuit,\spadesuit$ a card is.  "Color" would be ambiguous and would most often traditionally be treated as "red" vs "black" corresponding to $\diamondsuit,\heartsuit$ vs $\clubsuit,\spadesuit$ (*though some more modern decks use blue or green for $\diamondsuit$ and $\clubsuit$ respectively*).  The traditional name for what number/letter appears on a card would be "Rank."

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @JMoravitz: The German word for “suit” is the same as the word for “colour”; in the context of card games, this word is used with the meaning of “suit”. (I don’t know whether that’s also the case in other languages.)

Comment: It looks like the official answer forgot that when you draw a suit... you draw a suit.... and have one fewer than the full $13$.  The official answer seems to a assume you draw a suit.... and you still have $13$ left.  (The official answer is wrong)

Answer (score 2):

As has been discussed in the comments, your solution is correct and the one in the textbook is wrong. It seems they forgot to subtract the first card from its suit, which makes the numerators off by $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution $4\cdot(\dfrac{13}{52}\cdot\dfrac{12}{51}\cdot\dfrac{11}{50}\cdot\dfrac{10}{49}\cdot\dfrac{9}{48})$ is correct. This does simplify to $\dfrac{33}{16660}$. Your textbook actually just has the incorrect answer.